# How do I make an NSView move to the front of all NSViews

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I have a super view, which has 2 subviews.
These subviews are overlapped.

Whenever i choose a view from a menu, corresponding view should become the front view and handle actions.
i.e., it should be the front most subview.

`acceptsFirstResponder` resigns all work fine.
But the mouse down events are sent to the topmost sub view which was set.

Regards,
Dhana

Comment: beware that:

"Note: For performance reasons, Cocoa does not enforce clipping among sibling views ..."

And furthermore!

"Cocoa does not ... guarantee correct invalidation and drawing behavior when sibling views overlap."

As it says in the manual: "If you want a view to be drawn in front of another view, you should make the front view a subview (or descendant) of the rear view."

(from the View Programming Guide in the OSX doco)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here's another way to accomplish this that's a bit more clear and succinct:

```
[viewToBeMadeForemost removeFromSuperview];
[self addSubview:viewToBeMadeForemost positioned:NSWindowAbove relativeTo:nil];
```

Per the documentation for this method, when you use `relativeTo:nil` the view is added above (or below, with `NSWindowBelow`) all of its siblings.

Comment: There is a problem with the above approach. First, when you send **removeFromSuperview** to a view, it is released. So you first need to retain the view, then later balance the original retain with a release. Second, you have the overhead of removing and adding the view to the hierarchy (which may be costly depending on the complexity of your view hierarchy). There is another way of doing this which avoids having to remove and add views from the view hierarchy using NSView's built-in subview sorting function. See below.

Comment: I think the two lines of code still in the same event loop, so viewToBeMadeForemost won't be released before the second line.

Comment: @LiFumin, that is incorrect.  You are assuming that removeFromSuperview autoreleases the view, or that other code autoreleased it.  From the doc for -removeFromSuperview: "The view is also released; if you plan to reuse it, be sure to retain it before sending this message and to release it as appropriate when adding it as a subview of another NSView."  Dalmazio is correct, the view must be retained.  This solution also has problems regarding the breaking of constraints, etc., I would imagine.  It should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: another issue: remove from superview releases constraints

Comment: If you remove view that is being a first responder it will lose focus.

Answer (score 22):

using @Dalmazio's answer in a Swift 4 category that mimics the equivalent UIView method gives the following:

```
extension NSView {

    func bringSubviewToFront(_ view: NSView) {
            var theView = view
            self.sortSubviews({(viewA,viewB,rawPointer) in
                let view = rawPointer?.load(as: NSView.self)

                switch view {
                case viewA:
                    return ComparisonResult.orderedDescending
                case viewB:
                    return ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
                default:
                    return ComparisonResult.orderedSame
                }
            }, context: &theView)
    }

}
```

so, to bring `subView` to the front in `containerView`

```
containerView.bringSubviewToFront(subView)
```

unlike solutions which remove and re-add the view, this keeps constraints unchanged

Answer (score 17):

Another way is to use NSView's **sortSubviewsUsingFunction:context:** method to re-order a collection of sibling views to your liking. For example, define your comparison function:

```
static NSComparisonResult myCustomViewAboveSiblingViewsComparator( NSView * view1, NSView * view2, void * context )
{    
    if ([view1 isKindOfClass:[MyCustomView class]])    
        return NSOrderedDescending;    
    else if ([view2 isKindOfClass:[MyCustomView class]])    
        return NSOrderedAscending;    

    return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Then when you want to ensure your custom view remains above all sibling views, send this message to your custom view's superview:

```
[[myCustomView superview] sortSubviewsUsingFunction:myCustomViewAboveSiblingViewsComparator context:NULL];
```

Alternatively, you can move this code to the superview itself, and send the message **sortSubviewsUsingFunction:context:** to **self** instead.

Comment: @Jonathan. That's for UIViews which are part of the iOS framework. The question is about NSViews which are used for OS X apps.

Comment: This works, but appears to make the order of the rest of the subviews random, since the doc says "NSOrderedSame if their ordering isn’t important".  A solution that preserves the ordering of the rest of the views would be much better.  Also, the use of IsKindOfClass: here is weird; the question does not state that custom view subclasses are being used, or that the sibling subviews to be reordered are different classes.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this to work without calling removeFromSuperView

```
// pop to top
[self addSubview:viewToBeMadeForemost positioned:NSWindowAbove relativeTo:nil];
```

Comment: Does this create a new view rather than using the existing view?

Comment: This caused the app to hang forever.

Comment: If this works, it is just by accident; the docs make no guarantees as to the behavior of adding a view that is already added.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by just adding the view again; it will not create another instance of it.

```
[self addSubview:viewToBeMadeForemost];
```

You can Log the number of subviews before and after this line of code is executed.

Comment: If this works, it is just by accident; the docs make no guarantees as to the behavior of adding a view that is already added.

Answer (score 0):

Below given code should work fine..

```
    NSMutableArray *subvies = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self subviews]];//Get all subviews..

    [viewToBeMadeForemost retain]; //Retain the view to be made top view..

    [subvies removeObject:viewToBeMadeForemost];//remove it from array

    [subvies addObject:viewToBeMadeForemost];//add as last item

    [self setSubviews:subvies];//set the new array..
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it is closer to being correct than the others.  However, note that it ought to do a [viewToBeMadeForemost release]; at the end, otherwise there is a leak.

Answer (score -11):

You might try this:

```
[viewToBeMadeFirst.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

Comment: yes, this one works for me:  [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

Comment: We are talking about NSView, not NSWindow